# Should I create a new e-mail if my current one contains an online nickname?

Tags: professionalism, resume, email, unprofessional-behavior

I use a nickname that makes me identifiable anywhere on the internet. As neither Stack Overflow, nor most of the SE sites are related to my "internet persona", I decided not to register with that name here, but kept my full name instead.

My e-mail address, however reflects to this nickname. To be precise, it is (something like) `katamori123@email.com`, and I use it practically everywhere, even for receiving messages from the university.

Now, however, I have to apply to a job to gain experience (I can't have a degree without it) and I was asked for sending a CV via e-mail.

Would it ruin the image about me, if I use `katamori123` as usual? Is it recommended to make an e-mail like `zoltanschmidt@gmail.com` or it's safe to keep using the other one?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it's not a regular job, but rather about being a trainee or something. Couldn't find a better way of explaining; just my lack of proper English, I'm sorry. But anyways, it's general here,maybe even in the entire country.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere also, I've already checked the answer you tagged, but was unsure if I can consider that nickname unprofessional.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. It isn't offensive, and I promise you they've seen much worse geekery.

Comment: That name is not offensive to me but I am not a recruiter.   In the name of privacy and fraud I would not want an email name that could be guessed.

Comment: Does your university provide an email address? Since you are applying for trainee positions where they are presumably hiring university students, consider just using your uni-assigned address for this.

Comment: @Brandin I do have, but that is almost the same as my original one - `katamori@gamma.ttk.pte.hu`. The reason is that `katamori` is also my system account name at the university. I didn't think it has any significance beyond standanrd login procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely change it to something more professional.

Imagine the recruiter looking through a stack of resumes. Anyone with a ***killer_coyote_xxx@hotmail.com*** type of email is probably not getting a second look.

Additionally, when someone looks at their e-mail and sees a communication from "katamori12" they may just delete it thinking it came from some kind of spam bot.

Give yourself the best shot at any given job by having a clean, professional e-mail address listed.

> **Note:** And definitely consider making your resume e-mail a g-mail one. I've had recruiters set up my interview appointment through Google Calendar.

Comment: Yes, that very last sentence explains perfectly, why I was skeptical - even if user keshlam among the comments of the question is right.

Comment: If you're nervous, setting up a new mailbox more directly attached to your name certainly won't _hurt_.